# How to read a file (.txt) with many columns skipping some of them, with scanf()

Tags: c, scanf

I need to read data from a large *.txt* file, which contains many columns (122 of them) and I only need to read columns **3, 4 and 121**, using `scanf()`, in **C**. How do I do it without reading all 122 variables, skipping those I do not need?

Comment: I think this is C not C#. You might want to re-tag the question

Comment: Text files do not have columns and `c#` does not have `scanf()`

Comment: Are columns separated by commas or are they fixed width?  What is the scanf format?  You have to read the full line but then can use the string method split or use substring to get fixed width.

Comment: You can read each line in and split the lines by whatever delimiter separates the columns, that will give you an array then just pick out the ones you want to keep.

Comment: Please show a few lines from the text file.

Answer (score 1):

From [scanf documentation](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/scanf/), there is a syntax you could skip elements.

In order to skip a string, the syntax would be %*s

So, assuming you have the following format:

```
column0 column1 column2 column3 column4 column5
```

And you want to read `column3` and `column4`.

```
const char input_string [] = "column0 column1 column2 column3 column4 column5";
char s3[128], s4[128];
sscanf(input_string, "%*s%*s%*s%s%s", s3, s4);
```

Output:

```
s3 = "column3";
s4 = "column4";
```

Comment: To read `column3` it has to skip `column1` and `column2`, i.e.. skip 2. There is no `column0`.

Comment: You are correct - the sample input was not synchronised with the code. updated it.

Comment: I suspect that the OP is counting with 1 as the first column - adding that `column0` may confuse matters for them.

Comment: That's going to be a bit unwieldy when there 119 columns to be skipped.

Comment: @HildaCerdeira Just write another program to output the required number of `%*s` and `%s` then copy that into your program.